# jquery validation missing : after property id

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, jquery-validate

I changed my validation function a bit, because i wanted to include messages, and it throws missing : after property id now on line 2 in this code

```
    $("#order").validate({
        $("#vardas").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: { 
                required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
            }
        });
        $("#pavarde").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: { 
                required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
            }
        });
        $("#adresas").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            messages: { 
                required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
            }
        });
        $("#telef").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            digits: true,
            messages: { 
                required: "Reikalingas laukas",
                digits: "Turi susidaryti iš skaičių"
            }
        });
        $("#email").rules("add", {
            required: true,
            email: true,
            messages: { 
                required: "Reikalingas laukas",
                email: "Patikrinkite ar teisingai įvestas el. pašto adresas"
            }
        });

        submitHandler: function(form) {
            $(form).ajaxSubmit();
            $("#aciu").show(1000);
            $("#duomenysdiv").hide(500);
        }
    });
```

any idea what's going on?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can only call [`.rules()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/rules) after [`.validate()`](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#options) has run, and not within the object declaration (the reason for your current error).  Adding rules based on ID should look like this:

```
$("#order").validate({
    submitHandler: function(form) {
        $(form).ajaxSubmit();
        $("#aciu").show(1000);
        $("#duomenysdiv").hide(500);
    }
});
$("#vardas").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: { 
        required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
    }
});
$("#pavarde").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: { 
        required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
    }
});
$("#adresas").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    messages: { 
        required: "Reikalingas laukas" 
    }
});
$("#telef").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    digits: true,
    messages: { 
        required: "Reikalingas laukas",
        digits: "Turi susidaryti iš skaičių"
    }
});
$("#email").rules("add", {
    required: true,
    email: true,
    messages: { 
        required: "Reikalingas laukas",
        email: "Patikrinkite ar teisingai įvestas el. pašto adresas"
    }
});
```

Comment: That's great! That did not pop into my head. But now, for some reason, the digits:true rule applied to all inputs. What's going on?